# $Av=\lambda v \Rightarrow A^*v=\bar \lambda v$ (general case)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex inner product space and $v_1,v_2,...,v_3$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$.
Define $A:V \to V$ by $Av_i=\lambda_i v_i$ for some $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}.$
 Show that $A^*v_i=\bar \lambda v_i.$

My attempt:

$(Av_i,v_i)=(\lambda_iv_i,v_i)=(v_i,\bar\lambda_i v_i)=(v_i,A^*v_i)$

$\Rightarrow(v_i,(A^*-\bar \lambda_i)v_i)=0 \Rightarrow (A^*-\bar \lambda_i)v_i \perp v_i $

How to show that $(A^*-\bar\lambda_i)v_i=0$ ?

Comment: I have the same confusion. Do you find the answer now?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Just extend what you have a bit:
\begin{align}
  \langle \sum_j a_j v_j,A^*\sum_k b_k v_k \rangle = &\langle A \sum_{j}a_j v_j, \sum_{k}b_k v_k\rangle \\
   = & \langle \sum_{j}\lambda_j a_j v_j,\sum_k b_k v_k\rangle \\
   = &\sum_j\lambda_j a_j\overline{b_j} \\
   = &\langle\sum_j a_j v_j,\sum_k \overline{\lambda_k}b_kv_k\rangle \\
   \end{align}

Comment: @user1561 : Like the way I have redone it?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$+1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method:

Let $M=[A]_\beta$, where $\beta=\{v_i\}_{1\le i\le n}$. Then $\det\,(M-\lambda I)=0\implies\det\,(M-\lambda I)^*=0$.